# Converting an XML into GeoJson with Groovy

Tags: mongodb, groovy, geojson

I have been trying to use this great [example](https://dzone.com/articles/using-groovy-import-xml) in order to read XML files, convert them into GeoJson and ultimately import them into MongoDB.

My sample XML file looks like this:

```
<AName att1="sequence" att2="xx" att3="xxx">
    <Loc1>0</Loc1>
    <Loc2>0</Loc2>
</AName> 

<AName att1="sequence" att2="xx" att3="xxx">
    <Loc1>3</Loc1>
    <Loc2>6</Loc2>
</AName>
```

....

And my GEOJson structure should actually look like this (a typical [Polygon with a Single Ring](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/geojson/)):

```
{
  type: "Polygon",
  name: "sequence",
  coordinates: [ [ [ 0 , 0 ] , [ 3 , 6 ] , [ 6 , 1 ] , [ 0 , 0  ] ] ]
}
```

I have started playing with Groovy (which I never used before), but I am not sure whether the actual GeoJson creation does resemble my requirements (I do not actually think it has worked).

```
    //Here I am using the XmlSlurper() to parse the xml file

    def file=  new XmlSlurper().parse(new File('MyFile.xml'));
    def a = file.AName[0].@att1;
    println("AName " + a);
    def loc1= file.depthFirst().find() {it.name() == 'Loc1'};
    def loc2= file.depthFirst().find()  {it.name() == 'Loc2'};

   //Here I am converting the Java representation of my XML file to a GeoJson format

file.node.each {child ->
    Map myMap= [type: 'Polygon',
        name : a,
        loc: [coordinates: 
               [Double.valueOf(loc1),  Double.valueOf(loc2)],
               ]]

  //Finally I am inserting the BasicDBObject and creating the 2dsphere index

  collection.insert(new BasicDBObject(myMap));
  collection.createIndex(new BasicDBObject('loc', '2dsphere'));
```

While the index has been created, I see no records in my collection. Is there something obviously wrong in my code? Is the mapping recursively adding arrays of coordinates in my Polygon? Is there a way to better troubleshoot what it is going on? (I am currently using mongo-java-driver-3.2.1)

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: can you post some actual xml, and the actual json you would expect this to produce?

Comment: @time_yates, I have clarified the type of GeoJson I would like to achieve. Hope this helps.

Comment: But where are the coordinates in that XML? Where is the X attribute? Your example xml sends to bear no resemblance to the expected output, or the code

Comment: Now should be a bit better, have a look. Also refer to the example (link) posted from which I have taken the code: https://dzone.com/articles/using-groovy-import-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, came up with this:

```
import groovy.json.*

def xml = '''
<root>
<AName att1="sequence" att2="xx" att3="xxx">
    <Loc1>0</Loc1>
    <Loc2>0</Loc2>
</AName> 

<AName att1="sequence" att2="xx" att3="xxx">
    <Loc1>3</Loc1>
    <Loc2>6</Loc2>
</AName> 
</root>
'''

def doc = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

def polymap = [
    type: 'Polygon',
    name: doc.AName.head().@att1.text(),
    points: doc.AName.collect { [it.Loc1.text() as Double, it.Loc2.text() as Double] } 
]

def json = new JsonBuilder(polymap).toString()

assert json == '{"type":"Polygon","name":"sequence","points":[[0.0,0.0],[3.0,6.0]]}'
```

which does what you want (I think)

Comment: thanks for this, much appreciated Your solution does work, I only had to replace .head() with .find(). I wonder whether there is a better way to read the entire xml. I can do something like def file =  new XmlSlurper().parse(new File('C:\\file.xml')), but then how do you parse the entire content of the xml? Thanks, I.

Comment: I have read the entire file as mentioned before and passed it in to build the geographical structure and all works beautifully. Instead of 

collection.insert(new BasicDBObject(polymap ));

I simply used

collection.insertOne(new Document(polymap )); then created the 2dspehere.